# How can I get an entry based on category and slug (via url segments)?

Tags: relations, url, routes

I am using (and have used) [this S.O](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6837/building-a-simple-search-by-multiple-categories) post to create a product filter/search using multiple categories. Everything is working perfectly.

I am attempting to use the same type of logic to grab ultimately a single entry.

**TL;DR:** I am trying to get a single entry via 2 url segments.

I believe I am close, but what I am generating for a query isn't quite spot on as I'm always getting into my "No Products" clause.

```
www.mysite.com/products/toys/my-awesome-toy

{% set category = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}  {# toys #}
{% set product = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}   {# my-awesome-toy #}

{% set relationParam = ['and'] %}

{% if category|length %}
    {% set cat = craft.categories.group('toys').slug(category).first() %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: cat }]) %}
{% endif %}
```

`cat` is outputting `Toys` and my page renders all entries that belong to the `Toys` category group. **Perfect**.

```
{% if product|length %}
    {% set prod = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: prod }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entry = craft.entries.relatedTo(relationParam).first() %}

{% if entry %}
    {{ entry.title }}<br>
{% else %}
    <p>No products found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

`prod` is outputting `My Awesome Toy` and now I am getting my "No products found" message. I think it's because `prod` is outputting `My Awesome Toy` vs. `my-awesome-toy`?

I realize I can get any entry via it's slug alone. I am using a dynamic route to create this page that looks like this:

```
products/tag/slug
```

I would like to get the entry strictly based on the url segments that way I can make sure my urls are valid. Meaning, I can only find "My Awesome Toy" from the "toys" category. For example:

```
www.mysite.com/products/toys/my-awesome-toy   {# valid #}
www.mysite.com/products/food/my-awesome-toy   {# invalid #}
```

Comment: Rule out one thing. See if `my-awesome-toy` has an extra space behind it. `{% set prod = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)|trim).first() %}`

Answer (score 1):

An entry is not related to itself, but that's what you added as a filter.
Use the `slug` parameter instead.

```
{% set categorySlug = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set productSlug = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('products') %}

{% if categorySlug|length %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.group('toys').slug(category).first() %}
    {% if category %}
        {% set entries = entries.relatedTo({ targetElement: category }) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if productSlug|length %}
    {% set entries = entries.slug(productSlug) %}
{% endif %}

{% set product = entries.first() %}
```